# I'd like to extend my code however I don't know how to go about it

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and have recently learned how to convert from binary to denary vice versa. I'd like to make a program that allows me to put in a number (binary or denary) and for it to convert to one or the other. - Example- convert a binary number to denary vice versa. I have already figured out how to make the program convert from binary to denary however I want to make it so someone can convert from denary to binary. I am not too sure how to go about this. This is a piece of my code, if someone could kindly guide me that would be great.

```
def add2():

    binary = input('enter a number in binary: ')
    decimal = 0
    for digit in binary:
        decimal= decimal*2 + int(digit)

        print ("This is the decimal equivalent" , decimal,)​
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  There are many examples of base conversion on line.

Answer (score 0):

Call each function...

```
def binary_to_decimal(num):
    return int("{0:d}".format(num), 2)

def decimal_to_binary(num):
    return int("{0:b}".format(num))
```

[Coder Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151120/decimal-to-binary-conversion-and-vice-versa-in-python)

If you wanted to stick with your format, you could add another function...

```
denary = int(input("enter a number in denary:"))  
binary=""  
while denary > 0:   
  binary = str(denary % 2) + binary  
  denary = denary//2  
print("Your binary number is: " + binary)
```

[101 Computing](https://www.101computing.net/binary-converter-using-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Converting denary into binary:

```
denary= int(input('Denary: '))
binary= [0,0,0,0]
while denary>0:
     for n,i in enumerate(binary):
         if denary//(2**(3-n))>=1:
             binary[n]= 1
             denary -= 2**(3-n)
             print(denary)
print (binary)
```